# how to automatic create table in jpa persistence xml file?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, jpa

I am using eclipse IDE.I also try following two .but failed..when i manually create table in my mysql database then my complete program run fine... I want create table automatic with respect to entity class.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

here my persistence file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="JpaTest2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

     <class>com.jpa.Employee</class>

    <properties>

        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="umar"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="umar"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>


    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Do you think there's additional information that could help people trying to understand what's going on here? Or is this it?

Comment: markdown code properly

Comment: What's the expection after adding `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>` in `persistence.xml`?

Answer (score 16):

Dont use Hibernate specific options. JPA 2.1 provides

```
javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action
```

that can be set to "*create*", "*drop*", "*drop-and-create*", "*none*".
That way you keep your code JPA implementation independent

Comment: Seems to work for me. I agree that this is a preferred solution in order to make your bundles more generic

Comment: How do you prevent it from trying to create the same table on each restart?

Comment: @KennySteegmans If it already created the database, nothing will happen on next restart when set to 'create'

Comment: yes,perfect..@Neil Stockton

Answer (score 0):

Check your entity. Did you miss @Table annotation? The exception clearly says that the table is missing `'hibernate.employee'`:

`Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hibernate.employee' doesn't exist at ...`

If you defined a naming strategy that prepends all tables with *hibernate.*, then make sure that the tables are created in MySql.