# Is there a way to automatically create tables before adding object with JPA / eclipse link

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

My question is that if the tables are removed for whatever reason, is it possible to automatically add tables at runtime before object to table.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _adding an entity_? Persisting an instance of some `@Entity` class?

Comment: Hi I mean an object / row to the database, sorry for confusion

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32873844/6413377), if you mean table auto generation. BUT: this does not work to my knowledge without redeploy/container restart. I mean if your app is running and table removed it is not generated again automagically this way.

Comment: Look up the persistence property `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action`, with a value of "create"

Comment: Hi I am already using a similar property `<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>`. But basically you are spot on @pirho, is there a way if the table is removed to be generated again?

Comment: I am not aware of such thing - yet - but I suggest you to clarify your question and its title, so that someone than can possibly help spots this better. Removed table will be generated again - empty of course - but not without some trick, like restart/redeploy.