# JPA org.postgresql.util.PSQLException

Tags: java, jpa

I'm getting the exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException relation doesn't exist when trying to persist a player object in the player table but I thought that the persist method is able to create the table

```
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  p = new Player(playerName);
  em.persist(p);
  em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: "*I thought that the persist method is able to create the table*" - No. You can configure the underlying implementation (e.g. [Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779479/reverse-engineer-ddl-from-jpa-entities/779629#779629)) to create the database schema for you at startup. I would, however, recommend using a separate tool, e.g. [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) to create / migrate the database before application startup.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873844/how-to-automatic-create-table-in-jpa-persistence-xml-file

Comment: the generation schema action that i'm using is none so the above metioned solution is not right

Answer (score 1):

JPA does not create the schema for you on-demand.

You can configure the underlying implementation (e.g. [Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779479/reverse-engineer-ddl-from-jpa-entities/779629#779629))) to create the database schema for you at application startup. I would, however, recommend using a separate tool, e.g. [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) to create / migrate the database before application startup. Synopsis being that the migration is under one's control, i.e. one can create / migrate the schema when one sees fit and the database is not automatically migrated at application startup. This process cann then be incoroporated and automated in a fully-fledged deployment process through, e.g., [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).